# Tor won't even lauch

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, mac

[image]I am using OS X Mojave and I have downloaded Tor browser on the official website. However when I try to lauch as usual, an error message appears stating that Tos has been closed during launch.

Even when I copy the "Tor log", it is blank. There is no information whatsoever on the nature of the error.

Of course, I have allowed the application to be open on my computer. 
May I get some help?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to delete it and re-download it.

Comment: I have done that mutiple times with no result....

Comment: Maybe close all your internet connections down and then install.. Otherwise I wouldn't know

Comment: What a guess!!  And I suck at computers haha have a good one mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to reinstall the Tor browser completely, because the fact that the log is empty when you're copying it - it's either an antivirus software has broken your tor setup or the setup was not completed